# how to use path helpers with a custom `get` route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following line in my routes. (Rails 6.0.3.7)

```rb
namespace :api do
  namespace :xml do
    get ":resource_type/:id",
    resource_type: /[^\.]+/,
    id: /[\h-]+/,
    controller: "generic_resources",
    action: "show"
  end
end
```

I would then expect something like `api_xml_path 1, action: "show", resource_type: "as/df"` to return something like `/api/xml/as/df/1`. But instead I get `"/api/xml/as%2Fdf.1"`.

Is there a different way I should be invoking my `_path` helper here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails treats the value of each path parameter (e.g., `:resource_type`) as a single 'path segment' in URI syntax parlance. Per the [URI syntax spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.1), any reserved characters (which include delimiters like '/', '?', '#', etc.) within a segment must be percent-encoded, which Rails does automatically.

Put more simply, Rails doesn't know you're trying to use the `'/'` in `'as/df'` as a path delimiter, it just sees a string that needs encoding.

If you have generic, nested resources like that you're better off splitting the path spec itself so it has multiple parameters:

```rb
namespace :api do
  namespace :xml do
    get ":resource_type/:subtype/:id",
    ...
  end
end
```

And then:

```rb
api_xml_path 1, action: "show", resource_type: "as", subtype: 'df'
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why a dot separates the id from the rest of the path? I don't understand when a dot would be valid there in a url.